# Spring ApplicationContext cannot be resolved even with jar

Tags: java, spring

I have added the all spring distribution 3.1.1 jars to the build path which includes org.springframework.context-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
org.springframework.beans-sources-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar.

But still the eclipse build error says, 
*"The import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext cannot be resolved".*

Before adding the all jars in spring distribution 3.1.1, I have added jars manually one by one which includes, spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar and spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar. At that time the ApplicationContext recognized successfully. But then i thought adding jars one by one is waster of time and why not download all jars in latest spring distribution and give it to build path.

Initially i thought it might be a conflict with complied class in build forder because i build the project with diferent versions of context-sources jar. So i delete the build folder and clean the project too. Still the issue exists when i add spring 3.1.1 jars.

Comment: "But then i thought adding jars one by one is waster of time" you must be a very busy man indeed! My advice, do it the "right" way instead.

Comment: what i did was the right thing actually. download spring distribution and add the jars to build path

Comment: I have resolved this. the problem was i have added the source jars for the build path instead of .class jars. Need to add the jars inside the dist folder of spring distribution.

Comment: @FrankD - Haha, I have done that before. Glad you figured it out. You should post that as an answer, and close the question.

Answer (score 8):

Include these libraries:

- org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar and
- org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 3):

You have to include this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not the Spring-bean jar.You need **Spring-context** jar. You might have missed it while adding all jars together. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer is given in a lot of other threads, but still here is the solution that worked for me. Hope it helps somebody.

Step 1: Close Eclipse

Step 2:
Just go to your maven folder:-

C:\Users\Rohit.rokade.m2\repository\org

And delete the 'springframework' folder. (This contains all the maven dependencies related to spring)

Now open eclipse.

Step 3: Eclipse shall re-download all the dependencies and the errors should have gone by now. If some of them still don't, just update your maven project.
(Right click your project in eclipse -> Maven -> Update project)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add each of them, not just the directory. You can use Ctrl-click / mouse-drag to multi-select all the jars.

Answer (score 0):

The spring jars should be imported from "dist" folder not from "src" folder.
This will resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download org.springframework.context-2.5.6.a.jar.zip from
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgspringframeworkcontext256ajar.htm
and import it from build path. Will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue:

1. Open pom.xml
2. Click on "dependencies" tab at the bottom and click Add.
3. In artifactId - type "org.springframework"
4. In groupId - type "spring-core"
5. In search tab - type "springframework" and wait for couple of seconds.
6. Look for spring-context and add it.

Now, In the project explorer, right click on the project and search for Maven.
Click on "Update project.

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works with MacOS 10.15.7 + IntelliJ IDEA if you prefer adding any spring dependencies manually via project structure. otherwise using maven or other repos would definitely save the hassle. By the time this answer is written spring 5 has been launched.

1. press the shortcut keys `command` + `;` together to redirect to project structure, and click the libraries. In the library section, press the plus sign and it will prompt you to find the directory where you should locate the spring jar package.
2. Starting from where we were at the last step, if you have been working with Spring before on the same machine, it is very likely that you have installed Spring framework in your machine.
   Go to finder >`shift+command+h` to go to the home directory> `shift+command+.` to show hidden file. Find .m2 file, enter .m2>repository>org>spring-framework, click straight through the folders till you can see the `spring-context-versionnumber.jar` . Choose it and apply it, by now the `spring-conntext.jar` file would be successfully added to your working environment.
3. if step 2 is not your case, download the spring jar from here https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/release/org/springframework/spring/
   choose your desired version ends with `....RELEASE-dist.zip`, then unzip and locate the jar file in the same way as step 2 in the file you store the downloaded Spring release package.

Answer (score 0):

in **SpringToolSuite** IDE
add in **build.gradle**

```
//implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context'
```

and comment `spring-boot-starter` (optionally).
Then back to red underlined ApplicationContext word of the  main class click on crossed spot and select **Fix Project Setup** in dropdown window. save all, **project -> clean**  and reds should go